# Populate Combobox based on value of textbox in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have 1 textbox and 1 Combobox. Now what i want to do is that when user type in Textbox and then when he clicks on ComboxBox the combobox should automatically get filled from database. Below is my code.

```
    public void BindComboBox3(ComboBox comboBox3)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id FROM batch where product_id_fk='"+Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)+"'", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "batch");
        comboBox3.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        comboBox3.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["batch_id"].ToString();
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindComboBox3(comboBox3);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Enter Product ID " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *selection changed event of the combo box* should fire after the user click and select a different option. As if your combo box has nothing inside, the user have no way to change oneself the preference. That means the user have to do an extra clicking to fire it, or it just never fires.

You might consider other firing mechanism, such as *MouseUp or MouseDown, MouseHover of the combox*. You could set a breakpoint at the start of the event, so that you could know whether the event is fired from time to time, while you could separately ensure your code that update from the database does work.

Alternatively, you can trigger the combo box to change through the firing *text changed event of the textbox*.

Hope it helps.